# ExtJs loading mask displacement

Tags: javascript, extjs, loading, mask

I have some problems with Extjs 4.1.1 while using loading mask.

I have created a custom window and on a button press it sets the loading mask

```
var options=Ext.create('Ext.window.window',{
    title:'this window',
    height:200,
    width:100,
 items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
        xtype: 'grid',
        border: false,
        columns: [{header: 'World'}],              
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}) // A dummy empty data store
    }
}).show();

options.setLoading('Loading...');
```

After the load mask is enabled,if I open another window the mask is displaced from its place which is not desirable.
How should I prevent other windows from affecting the loading mask.

Or should I put mask over the entire frame instead of just the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creating duplicate windows are neccesarry, you can check the window is created before. If it exits, do not need to setLoading. Look at this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tv5

```
    var me = this;
    var x = 50;
    var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: 'click',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        closable: true,
        handler: function() {

            me.options = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                title:'this window',
                height:200,
                width:400,
                items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'here' // A dummy empty data store
                }
            });

            me.options.show();

            me.options.setXY([x+30, x+30]);
            me.options.mask('Loading1...');

        }
    });

    var button2 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: 'click',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        closable: true,
        handler: function() {
            me.options2 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                title:'this window',
                height:200,
                width:400,
                items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'here' // A dummy empty data store
                }
            });

            me.options2.show();

            me.options2.setXY([x+200, x+300]);

            me.options2.mask('Loading2...');

        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not opening the same window again.It is a different window.
And the link does not work.

Comment: Well. I thought you used same window template for anothers. I fixed my code as you mentioned, but I couldn't face to your problem.. Please check it again. And it is possible to provide a working fiddle? It would be more helpful.

Comment: The structure is pretty complex which I can not replicate completely on fiddle.But your answer is nowhere close to solution to problem which is probably because of lack of information about the problem itself.
Anyway I appreciate your efforts.